# Comparing Date and Time between Cells and Create a versioning column on which appeared first

Tags: excel, vba

[screen shot of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRoma.png)

Hello,
I have 3 columns in my excel sheet. Column A is item number, Column B is file Name, Column C is the date/time that file was modified(it is called matched in excel). I created a column D called versioning by comparing date and time of files with the same item number, right now I am doing this manually, Is it possible that it can be automated?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can an Item number show up again later on in the list after a different Item number or will they all be grouped together

Comment: Item numbers are all grouped together @JohnBustos

Comment: I came up with a generic solution and posted it, it should work regardless...

Comment: it works Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data has column headings in row 1, so data begins on row 2 and version begins on cell `D2` and, just say your data stretches down to, say, row 100, you could use the following formula in cell `D2`:

```
D2: =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,A2,$C$2:$C$100,"<="&C2)
```

Basically, you're saying `For every file with the same Item number, how many have a date/time less than or equal to this row's?`
That will, in effect, give you a version number.

---

As requested in the comment, to explain this formula in a bit greater depth, let's break it down:

**Heading Match:**

- `CountIfs($A$2:$A$100,A2`:

  This portion is saying "Only count if the value in `$A$2:$A$100` = the value in `A2`" - Therefore, only count rows where the item number is the same as the one in the current row

**Versioning:**

- `CountIfs($C$2:$C$100,"<="&C2`:

  This portion is saying "Count the number of dates LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO `C2`" - Therefore, how many dates do we have that are less than or equal to the date in this current row.

So, if you put them both together, you get:

1) Only count a value with the item number is the same as this current row
  2) And, of those, how many rows contain a date that is less than or equal to the date contained in the current row.

That, in effect, gives you a version number for every row.

Hope that does it.

Comment: Would you be able to explain the logic behind this? I seem to get it but would like to know how its working

Comment: @KaranNeginhal, I just added in an explanation - Hope it helps, but also just read up on the `CountIfs` formula too. That may fill in any remaining blanks.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your cell D2: (you may need to make the ranges bigger):`=1+SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($C$2:$C$18>C2))`